# How does google swirl work?

Tags: flash, jquery-ui

I have seen [this image swirl effect](http://image-swirl.googlelabs.com/html?q=eiffel%20tower#454) on a visual thesaurus. Is there any open source code for this?

I don't care about the algorithm to match similar objects. I only am wondering about the effects.

Comment: Do you have a link that demonstrates the effect?

Comment: @Mark: http://image-swirl.googlelabs.com/html?q=eiffel%20tower#454

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Thanks... that really should be part of the question IMHO. I'll edit it.

Comment: that's totally awsome! try it with "david hasselhoff" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is such a thing for flex: http://mark-shepherd.com/blog/2006/11/17/a-flex-component-for-graph-visualization/

without looking at the code, I guess it should be quite easy to port to pure ActionScript. Maybe you can even use it as a starting point for a JavaScript port.

greetz
back2dos